# Spring Boot Application restarts when using with AWS s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to my S3 Bucket using Spring Boot.
Upload is successful but immediately after the file is uploaded, My application restarts.
THIS IS MY CODE

ServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class AmazonS3ClientServiceImpl implements AmazonS3ClientService
{
    private AmazonS3 amazonS3;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AmazonS3ClientServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    public AmazonS3ClientServiceImpl(Region awsRegion, AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider)
    {
        this.amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider)
            .withRegion(awsRegion.getName()).build();
    }

    @Async
    public void uploadFileToS3Bucket(MultipartFile multipartFile, boolean enablePublicReadAccess,String bucketname)
    {
        String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();

        try {
            //creating the file in the server (temporarily)
            File file = new File(fileName);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(multipartFile.getBytes());
            fos.close();

            PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketname, fileName, file);

            if (enablePublicReadAccess) { 
                putObjectRequest.withCannedAcl( CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
            }
            //            this.amazonS3.putObject(putObjectRequest);
            TransferManager tm = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withS3Client(this.amazonS3).build();
            Transfer transfer = tm.upload(putObjectRequest);
            transfer.waitForCompletion();
            //removing the file created in the server
            file.delete();
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException |AmazonServiceException ex) {
                logger.error("error [" + ex.getMessage() + "] occurred while uploading [" + fileName + "] ");
            }
        }

        @Async
        public void deleteFileFromS3Bucket(String fileName)
        {
            try {
                 amazonS3.deleteObject(new DeleteObjectRequest("scts1545321420734", fileName));
            } catch (AmazonServiceException ex) {
                logger.error("error [" + ex.getMessage() + "] occurred while removing [" + fileName + "] ");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void createBucket(String bucketname) {
        try {
            amazonS3.createBucket(bucketname);
        }catch(SdkClientException e) {
            logger.error("error [" + e.getMessage() + "] occurred while creating bucket ["+ bucketname + "]");
        }
     }
}
```

REST CONTROLLER

```
@PostMapping("/supplier-masters/logo")
public ResponseEntity<AgroWebResponse> testLogo(@RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file){

    amazonS3ClientService.uploadFileToS3Bucket(file, true, "scts1545321420734");
    return CommonWebUtils.successResponse("Uploadaed");
}
```

EXCEPTION BEFORE Restart: `InterruptedException`

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I think you are complicating the code. You can put the object with just these three lines.`ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    metadata.setContentLength(multipartFile.getSize());this.amazonS3.putObject(BUCKET_NAME, multipartFile.getName(), multipartFile.getInputStream(), metadata);`

Comment: @FedericoPiazza My Server Restarts after each upload.I would like to know why and how to stop it

Comment: @ShylanthurKanagavel It mostly likely happening because you are deleting the file. Why are you creating a file on the server?

Comment: @Nikhil I'm converting MultipartFile into File.

Comment: @Nikhil Thank you.Your Snippet stopped server from restart but it causes a minor error Log.The Log is 2018-12-26 19:20:24.119 ERROR 10680 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] io.undertow.request                      : UT005005: Cannot remove uploaded file C:\Users\SHYLAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\undertow3880568785480563139upload

Comment: @Nikhil Please explain why the above error log occurs.Also what was wrong in my original code?I'm new to AWS so please explain it to me.

Comment: @ShylanthurKanagavel Great! You don't have to create the `File`. Remove all the code that does that and it should work without any errors.

Comment: You are taking a two-step process. You are first downloading the file to the server then uploading to s3. You can skip the downloading part and set the input stream directly to s3 as in my code.